# Pass by reference in C++ vs C#

Tags: c#, c++, oop, object

In C# you're able to pass an object to a function and the changes made to the properties/members of that object remain.

Is the use of pointers necessary to do this in C++?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can do exactly the same thing with non-const references in C++.

As for the differences between references and pointers, check out this thread:

[What are the differences between pointer variable and reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a non-const reference to do this...

```
void square(int32_t& x) {

    x = x * x;

}
```

It's generally a bad practice to mutate things in non-member function calls though, since it makes it more difficult for the caller to reason about state after calling it.

It's usually better to pass by value or reference to const...

```
int64_t square(const int32_t& x) {

    return x * x;

}
```

Comment: _It's generally a bad practice..._ is nonsense.

Comment: We all know there are exceptions, but code that prefers pure functions to non-pure functions is *generally* easier to reason through and debug.  Side effects are a necessary evil.

Comment: "Side effects are a necessary evil", no, if you believe so just use functional programming.

Comment: Functional concepts are just as relevant in C++.  The 11/14 specs even added a number of the constructs to the language (lambdas, auto type deduction, etc...).

Answer (score 1):

No.

In C++, you might want to do this:

```
int someNumber = 2;

void modifyNumber (int& number)
{
   number = number + 1;
}


int main ()
{
std::cout << someNumber;
modifyNumber (someNumber);
std::cout << someNumber;
return 0;
}
```

The output of the above would be:

> 2
>
> 3

By using the ampersand sign in the argument, you pass a variable by reference.

However, the ampersand is also used to signify the address of a variable when assigning one.
i.e.:

```
int someNumber = 0; //create an integer variable
int* pointer = &someNumber; //assign the pointer to point to the address of someNumber
```

Careful.

Comment: Your code is incorrect.  You're passing an address, *not* a reference.  You can't modify a function signature by changing the call context.